# Middleware in the router taking too long to send the response

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, express-jwt

I am using the middleware function to get the user id from the jwt token and it is working completely fine but I want it to send a response when there is no jwt header in the request which it's doing. Here is the code:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const fetchuser = (req, res, next) => {
  const jwtToken = req.header("jwt-token");
  if (!jwtToken) {
    console.log(2);
    return res
      .status(401)
      .status({ error: "This action requires the user to login" });
  }
  try {
    const data = jwt.verify(jwtToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    if (data.user) {
      if (data.user.status === 1) {
        req.user = data.user;
      } else {
        return res.status(500).status({ error: "User account is disabled" });
      }
    } else {
      return res
        .status(401)
        .status({ error: "This action requires the user to login" });
    }

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .status({ error: "This action requires the user to login" });
  }
};

module.exports = fetchuser;
```

It's definitely going in the first if block as required when the header is absent but it's not sending the response back, the request keeps buffering

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Sorry about that, I changed it to text format

Comment: ```return res.status(401).status({ error: "This action requires the user to login" });``` Maybe a typo here. the second `status` should be `json` ?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh that's indeed the issue, feel free to make it an answer :D

Answer (score 2):

This block is where the problem occurs:

```
return res
      .status(401)
      .status({ error: "This action requires the user to login" });
```

`status` is used to set the http status code for the response. To send the response to the client, you can use `json`.

It should be:

```
return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ error: "This action requires the user to login" });
```

You need to do the same thing for other blocks.